# Search results test returns duplicates when run by automation but running manually does not show duplicates

Tags: appium

Any ideas why when I run appium automation my search results test returns duplicates but when run manually it doesn't do that?

Is there anything I should take a look at? Has anyone come across a similar problem? Please provide some suggestions.

Comment: "my search results test returns duplicates" can you clarify what it means?

Comment: I get apple and another exact apple returned. I see two apples using automation to search which is incorrect. But if I search manually I see only one apple which is correct. I think Yu mentioned a good point that automation is very fast so maybe I should add in some thread sleep to force it to wait a bit maybe that can stop it from rendering duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- timing, automated tests are executed in an instant comparing to manual testing. An action that is too fast or too slow can cause unexpected behaviours
- testing environment, automated tests can be executed on a different environment. Different environments may produce different results even the actions taken are identical.
- testing variables, automated tests can have different variables than manual testing and more than often, there are variables that we are not aware of.

The steps I will take to diagnose this problem are:

- Produce a flow chart based on automated tests, writing down all variables and environments
- Try to re-execute the tests using this flow chart, are results any different?